# Getting a Property list with similar name for looping c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class with several properties

```
public class Hotel
{
   public string ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Location {get; set;}
   public Image Image1 {get; set;}
   public Image Image2 {get; set;}
   public Image Image3 {get; set;}
   public Image Image4 {get; set;}
}
```

I want to get a list of all the properties starting with property name "Image"
ex

```
public List<Image> GetImageList(Hotel hotel)
{
  List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
  foreach(var item in <ImageList>)
  {
    rest of the code .....
  }

  return imageList ;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a property  `List<Image> HotelPictures`? Then you could even add a fifth or sixth image ;-)

Comment: You should definetely store it in `List<Image>`. Looping through is not a good idea.

Comment: No, The problem is the class "Hotel" is an auto generated one. No of Image Type fields depend on another frame work.

Comment: Well, what auto-generates it and what is the source of the generation? If that's a database table you should definitley normalize that and remove the `Image`-columns out of the table.

Comment: It is from another framework...
not similar to the ef

Comment: @Sameera Mind telling us which framework? The way it's auto generated is the 'wrong' way.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, as a *quick and dirty* solution, you can try *reflection*:

```
   using System.Reflection;

   ...

   // Properties; some conditions like property.CanRead && property.CanWrite 
   // can well appear redundant, but since the class is not yours,
   // better be a bit paranoic esp. having run into a bad design 
   var properties = hotel
     .GetType()
     .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
     .Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite) // Not necessary 
     .Where(property => property.Name.StartsWith("Image"))
     .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof(Image)); // Not necessary

   // Properties' values, i.e. images
   List<Image> list = properties
     .Select(property => property.GetValue(hotel) as Image)
     .Where(image => image != null) // if you want to filter out nulls
     .ToList();
```

However, it's the high time for you to redesign the routine:

1. *Normalize* the db table (push images into a separate table)
2. *Redesign* `Image1..Image4` into `IList<Image>` or alike *collection*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can get all the `PropertyInfos` using `Reflection` and reuse them when calling `GetImageList` with different `Hotel` instances:

```
private static List<PropertyInfo> hotelImages = GetHotelImageProperties();

private static List<PropertyInfo> GetHotelImageProperties()
{
    return typeof(Hotel)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(Image))
        .Where(x => x.CanRead)
        .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Image"))
        .ToList();
}
```

Then, each time `GetImageList` is called, just get the values of the properties:

```
public static List<Image> GetImageList(Hotel hotel)
{
    return hotelImages
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(hotel))
        .Cast<Image>()
        .ToList();
}
```

---

With that said, it's important to notice that ***reflection is slow*** and should be avoided when it is not *really* required, more than that, the properties are probably known at compile time or can be represented as some `IEnumerable<Image>` to allow a better design (more flexible, fast and type-safe).

If it is generated from a database or some other scheme, you should consider representing it or generating it as some collection type.

Answer (score 0):

Getting properties that way needs reflection, and since reflection isn't that great for performance. I got a much better solution for you:

```
public class Hotel
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}
    public List<Image> Images {get; set;}
}
```

This way you can just use:

```
Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
// Set properties
List<Image> imagesFromHotel = hotel.Images;
```

Wouldn't that be MUCH easier? You can also easier add more images. You wouldn't need to add more properties for more images.

Comment: I'd say the greatest disadvantage of using reflection isn't the performance impact but the loss of compile time safety. Maybe someone refactors your code in future and that method `GetImageList` breaks silently. It would just return an empty list then.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hmm well I just know it gives a decrease on performance; all I heard about reflection. In either case, using reflection isn't the best idea.

Comment: Thank you for the response...
We cannot create a List<Image> because the class Hotel is auto generated. only thing we know is those properties start with "Image" and has a running no as a suffix

Comment: @Sameera If this is auto generated from a database; you are clearly doing something wrong. As you should use another table and foreign keys for the images. This way you can easy add new images. I have no clue which other way it'd be auto generated.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker: if this method is only called once you don't need to care about a millisecond more or less, but you always have to care about that it works. Reflection is dangerous.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hmm true, it's morning and I don't want to assume it's only called once, I'll edit my answer once I know what Sameera's reaction is on my (and probably your) comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to loop through the Hotel properties, and take the values from the Image types:

```
public List<Image> GetImageList(Hotel hotel)
    {
        List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
        var type = hotel.GetType();
        var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var item in propertyInfos)
        {
            if (item.Name.StartsWith("Image") && item.PropertyType==typeof(Image))
            {
                imageList.Add((Image)item.GetValue(hotel));
            }
        }

        return imageList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an enumerable sequence of `Image` which returns the `Image` for each public property with a name that begins with "Image":

```
var images =
    from   property in hotel.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    where  property.Name.StartsWith("Image") && property.PropertyType == typeof(Image)
    select (Image) property.GetValue(hotel);
```