# Is there a way of restricting a foreach loop thorugh a class's properties in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, properties

I'm trying to create a class method to fill some flag properties from an integer value containing which flags are true when in binary. The idea of the method is to loop through the flag properties one by one and set them according to the correspondent bit in the integer.

As far as I understand it, using this structure

```
public void FillFlags( int combinedFlags )
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in GetType().GetProperties() )
    {
         //Do Something
    }
}
```

will iterate through *all* of the properties of the instantiated object.

Is it possible to limit the loop to, say, only the properties under a region?

Like:

```
#region Flags
public bool HAS_POSITION { get; set; }
public bool HAS_SOURCE { get; set; }
public bool HAS_DESTINATION { get; set; }
public bool HAS_SUBJECT { get; set; }
#endregion
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition.

Comment: No, regional are only in source code

Comment: You can add an `Attribute` to the properties you want to iterate over

Comment: You could apply a custom Attribute to the properties you want to process.

Comment: It should be possible to include only properties [starting with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41013034/1997232) `"HAS_"`.

Comment: Off-topic, but properties in C# should be written in PascalCase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, regions are not available at runtime.

You can for instance create an attribute and use it on the properties that you want to iterate.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ReflectThisAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[ReflectThis]
public bool HAS_POSITION { get; set; }

[ReflectThis]
public bool HAS_SOURCE { get; set; }

[ReflectThis]
public bool HAS_DESTINATION { get; set; }

[ReflectThis]
public bool HAS_SUBJECT { get; set; }
```

Which enables you to:

```
public void FillFlags( int combinedFlags )
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in GetType().GetProperties() )
    {
         if (prop.GetCustomAttribute<ReflectThisAttribute> == null)
             continue;

         // Only get here if the property have the attribute
    }
}
```

You could also check if it's a `bool`:

```
public void FillFlags( int combinedFlags )
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in GetType().GetProperties() )
    {
         if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(bool))
             continue;

         // Only get here if the property is a bool
    }
}
```

**However!**

Since it looks like the `FillFlags` method is part of the class that you want to change I would recommend that you assign the properties manually in it. The code will become much more readable than trying to use reflection.

Reflection is typically used to generalize solutions. For instance:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class FlagValueAttribute : Attribute
{
     public FlagValueAttribute (int value)
     {
         Value = value;
     }

     public int Value{get;set}
}

public class SomeEntity
{

    [FlagValue(1)]
    public bool HAS_POSITION { get; set; }

    [FlagValue(2)]
    public bool HAS_SOURCE { get; set; }

    [FlagValue(4)]
    public bool HAS_DESTINATION { get; set; }

    [FlagValue(8)]
    public bool HAS_SUBJECT { get; set; }
}

public static class EntityExtensions
{

    public static void FillFlags(this object instance, int combinedFlags )
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in instance.GetType().GetProperties() )
        {
             var attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<FlagValueAttribute>();
             if (attr == null)
                 continue;

             if ((attr.Value & combinedFlags) != 0)
                 prop.SetValue(instance, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myEntity = new SomeEntity();

// will set HAS_SOURCE and HAS_SUBJECT to true
myEntity.FillFlags(10);
```

Comment: Does it have to be a custom attribute or would something like `[Category("Flag")]` work as well?

Comment: @RafaSinhoroto that can work, yes. But for this specific use-case, I recommend it to be a custom attribute, not something that can have side-effects without you knowing.